# Angular2 - Import barrels cause 404 at runtime

Tags: import, typescript, angular

I am trying to implement the import barrels structure that is described in this link (you may have to scroll down a bit) :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#application-structure

The problem I am facing is that the index.ts files that I am creating and referencing like

```
import {...} from './shared/services';
```

are not found at runtime and are throwing 404s. If I reference the modules like

```
import {...} from './shared/services/index';
```

It works fine. The problem only appears at runtime, typescript does not complain and compiles successfully. I have duplicated the issue in a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ClE76zuihFTETLDGehnd?p=preview

You can see the error in the console.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior by myself. I will take a deeper look at this problem and will inform you if I was able to find something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found something: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4i2d9x/support_problem_with_barrels/

It seems, that this is not easily possible with `SystemJS`, because it can not handle barrel-files.

To solve this, you can add every file as you did with `[...]/index` or you can add them as a package in `SystemJS`

Comment: That was indeed the case! Thanks @Dinistro. I added separate packages for all my index.ts files. It may feel a bit smelly in the SystemJS configuration but the overall code is a lot cleaner.